# cephfs mount: can't open files with LibreOffice

Tags: mount, file-permissions, ceph, openoffice, cephfs

I'm able to open/write different relevant filetypes with other applications (vim,code,gedit,...) from remote cephfs storage.
libreoffice has been configured to prevent file-locks.
All dirs and files have full posix rw permissions and they're without ACLs.
Security-applications like AppArmor or selinux are deactivated.

Libreoffice tells me: Access to /bla/blubb/myfile was denied

But ... I haven't probs to use these files from local storage ...

I ran out of ideas ... any suggestions?